# How can I make php pages appear inside a div?

Tags: php

How can I make PHP pages appear inside a div called contenct, whenever a menu button is pressed?

For example I should bring product menu product.php page to the document body and head, footer will continue well without causing alteration.

I've tried `include`, but how could it put the link from appearing on the container div?
I hope I have understood!

leave a sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, im assuming you would like to page to NOT refresh when the navigation button is pressed, and to simply load the contents of a php file into the content area.

The smart way to do this would be to look into using jquery with AJAX, or LOAD to load external content as needed.

PHP has no direct way to manipulate the clients browser without refreshing or loading another page.

if you must do this in php, a very simple approach would be to have each menu item link to a query string. I.E.

HTML: `menu.php`

```
<a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a>
<a href="index.php?page=products">Products</a>
<a href="index.php?page=clients">Clients</a>
<a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>
```

and to have the index.php file itself run a switch and case I.E.

PHP: `index.php`

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '' ){    
    $page = $_GET['page']; // page being requested
  }else{
    $page = 'home'; // default page
  }

  include('head.php');
  include('menu.php');

  // Dynamic page based on query string
  include($page.'.php');

  include('footer.php');

?>
```

This is a very basic example, but might get you pointed in the right direction.

hope this helps

Comment: Very clear his explanation!!, Thanks for understanding. Well he had not dimensioned before and what I need is something like the asp.net mvc or asp.net ago web page (WebMatrix), it does <div id="main"> @ RenderBody () </ div>.
But with the explanation that I super-clear and fit DYNAMIC!

Comment: umm.. i'll assume by what i could interpret from your comment, this helped then??

Comment: Also note, on each dynamic page, you could just start the page with <div id="main"> your content here </div> on every body page, which allows header, nav, and footer to wrap around it the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for that purpose.

An example:

```
<?php
include('head.php');
include('menu.php');

//your normal body code goes here

include('footer.php');
?>
```

include('file.php'); will read the contents of the php file and it will add / paste the contents in the main file. In this particular example, it will load the contents of head.php, menu.php, and footer.php.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, and what would happen if I press the corresponding menu contact.php
and rendered in id = "contenct" then pressed products to renderise in id = "contenct" product.php, contact.php section disappears!

Comment: @user1594109: If you want all pages to have the same layout, you can just include the same files over and over again using the same method in those pages. And whenever you want to edit the links, you can just edit the respective include file and the changes will reflect in all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

In the php file the user is viewing, put:

```
include('home.php');
```

this will execute the contents of the home.php file in the current php file

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX and on the event's finish use result `$('#content').empty().append(result)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add AMAL's answer...

```
<?php
require('function.php');
include('head.php');
include('menu.php');

//Create a function here to fetch pages
echo '<div id="content">';
echo get_page();
echo '</div>';

include('footer.php');
?>
```

Then create a function page and add a function that parse the url and gets the php page. (quickly made function, but should do the trick, or help)

```
function get_page()
{
        //http://example.com?page=home
        $page = $_GET("page");
            $directory = "pages";
        if($page){
        //security check (anti-hack)
            if (!strpos($page,".")&&!strpos($page,"/")&&!strpos($page,"\\")&&!strpos($page,";")){
                $path= $directory."/".$page.".php";
                if (file_exists($path)){
                    require ($path);
                }else{
                    echo "<p>Sorry, but that page does not exist.</p>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<p>Sorry, but those characters aren't allowed !</p>";
            }
        }else{
                $path = $directory."/home.php";
                require ($path);
        }
}
```

Then your php page should look like this:

```
<p>This is the home page</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code in the content area of your content area in main file...

`<li><a href="mainfile.php?page=blog.php">BLOG</a></li>`

```
<div class="container content">

     <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page_name = $_GET['page'];
        include("/".$page_name);
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```